# why the value of integral conflicts with the graph?

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals

Considering the graph of $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$, both of the function’s integration from $x=1$ to $x=\infty$ looks like a finite number but $\frac{1}{x}$ is not finite. I know mathematicly this is correct but why one is finite but one is infinite when the graphs look very similar?

Comment: The plot of $\ln(x)$ looks like it might flatten out as $x$ gets arbitrarily large, but it doesn't, it just rises very slowly. Looks are deceiving.

Comment: what is this have to do with the graph of ln(x)? I’m talking about the graph of 1/x

Comment: My point is that you can't judge the behavior of a function just by *looking* at it. I just used the plot of $\ln(x)$ as an example to demonstrate that point. But on top of that, the area you're talking about is$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln(x)$$so my allusion to $\ln(x)$ is not accidental. It would be a mistake to say that this limit and hence the area is finite just because the graph of $\ln(x)$ *looks like* it converges.

Comment: i know its 1/x’s antiderivative. Mathematically it is infinite but i just wanted to know why the graph looks the same with 1/x^2 but the area under it doesn’t end